# How summation of theta(1) over n times is theta(log n base 2)

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

If `T(n) = theta(1) + theta(1) + theta(1) +...(n times)...+ theta(1)`

How, can we write `T(n) = theta(log(n) base 2)`.

How is `1+1+1+..+1 = log(n) base 2`?

Comment: Where did you read this? Is it a true/ False question? What are some statements that follow? Need some context here

Comment: This doesn't seem to be well-defined; what does `+` mean in this context? Theta(1) is a set of functions.

Comment: What is `theta` here, the big theta operator indicating the function is bounded from above and below? Then `Tin) = theta(log(n))` simply isn't true.

Comment: Well, it's a divide and concur algorithm's worst case scenario:
T(n) = T(n/2) + theta(1)
T(1) = theta(1)
now, it was said T(n) = theta(log n base 2). How's that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does not seem possible, assuming `theta(1) + theta(1)` means the set of all functions that are the sum of two functions that are each `theta(1)`. Let `f1, f2, …, fn` be functions that are all `theta(1)`. Then each assumes some minimum positive value `v1, v2, …, vn` since, if they dipped to zero or below, they would fail to be `Omega(1)` as required. Among these values there must be some smallest value; let us call this v. The sum `f1 + f2 + … + fn` cannot assume a value lower than `v1 + v2 + … + vn` which in turn must me no less than `v + v + … + v`. This is equal to `vn`. Thus, it seems that the sum of `n` functions all `theta(1)` must have a value that is at least proportional to `n`.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense; in what sense can a sum of constant functions not be a constant function? The n in the summation expression cannot sensibly be the same n that is the argument of the functions; whatever sum of functions f is defined as, it can't be both that f(3)=f1(3)+f2(3)+f3(3) and also f(4)=f1(4)+f2(4)+f3(4)+f4(4), since those f's aren't the same sum of functions, so they aren't the same f. I think the question is just meaningless, and hiding behind a misuse of notation.

Comment: @kaya3 The sum of functions constant w.r.t. some variable remains constant w.r.t. that variable; however, it is not constant w.r.t. the number of functions being added together. As a concrete example: if `fk(x) = k`, then the sum of f1, f2, …, fn is the constant function F(x) = 1 + 2 + … + n = n(n+1)/2, which is a constant function with respect to x but which is quadratic with respect to n. FWIW,  I agree the question is not one typically asked and may betray a misunderstanding of the issues.

Comment: Agreed about that; my point being that it only makes sense if x and n are different variables. The result is a function of x, so it's in Theta(1).

Comment: Or you could say it's a family of functions of x, where the family is parameterized by n, but each function in the family is in Theta(1).